# Converting an array with 50,000+ entries into a mysql database

Tags: php

Ok, so I am helping someone with their site. Their original coder thought it would be a great idea to put their entire database in an array.

I am looping through each piece of data in the array and inserting it into a new mysql table I created, the rows are getting inserted just fine but the problem is that php wont let my script execute for more than 60 seconds.

How can I override this setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the classic solution, using [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)(), which allows you to set the maximum execution time (in seconds) for a script.

Still, you might want to either insert multiple rows with one query or convert the array into CSV and use LOAD DATA which is much faster.

**Edit**: examples

Inserting multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Using LOAD DATA:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 4):

Solutions:

- Set `max_execution_time` to 0 in the php.ini or use `set_time_limit()`
- Run the PHP script at the command-line. The time limit for CLI scripts is hardcoded to 0 already.
- Dump the array out to a CSV file and then use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to make the database import go 20x faster than inserting one row at a time in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function at the top of your page, as follows:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ini_set('max_execution_time', $time_in_seconds);`

[Source](http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli I would use [multi_query](http://no.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to batch the operations. The whole thing will run a lot faster.